# Made a cursor in pygame and having trouble with detecting it's collisions from the window and surface

Tags: python, pygame

I have made a cursor to follow my mouse around in pygame. In my game I have a surface which is 2000x2000 and then currently my window size is 1920x1080.

I was the cursor to change when it is over an enemy. However since the enemy is blitted on the background surface and the cursor is blitted on the game window the positions are different. Before you say I have tried blitting the cursor on the background surface but the cursor is offset from the mouse.

```
    def __init__ (self,x,y):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("crosshair.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(40,40))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def get_rect(self):
        return self.rect

    def get_x (self):
        return self.rect.x

    def get_y(self):
        return self.rect.y

    def get_rect(self):
        return self.rect

    def get_image(self):
        return self.image


    def draw(self,game_window):
        self.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        #game_window.blit(self.image,self.rect)
        
        
    def collision(self,enemy):
        if (enemy.get_rect()).colliderect(self.get_rect()) == 1:
            self.image = pygame.image.load("crosshairActive.png").convert_alpha()
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(40,40))
        else:
            self.image = pygame.image.load("crosshair.png").convert_alpha()
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(40,40))
```

Here is the class for the cursor.
Here is the whole code if you want to take a look too
https://github.com/SR-S225/pygametest

Hope this helps

Thank you

Comment: Are you scaling the background or is the background scrolling?

Comment: There is a camera class which is moving over the background when the player moves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the offset of the top left corner of the background map to the position of the enemy. In the following `background_left_x` and `background_top_y` are the placeholders for the offsets which you have to get from the camera:

```py
def collision(self,enemy):
        
    enemy_rect = enemy.get_rect()
    enemy_rect.x += background_left_x
    enemy_rect.y += background_top_y

    if enemy_rect.colliderect(self.get_rect()) == 1:
        self.image = pygame.image.load("crosshairActive.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(40,40))
    else:
        self.image = pygame.image.load("crosshair.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(40,40))
```

Comment: @Shay I have explained it in the answer. It is the top left position of the background map. The background is not placed at (0, 0), but somewhere else depending on your "camera"

Comment: I see what you mean now. I set the enemy_rect.x and y in the procedureto the x and y of the camera and it causes the actual enemy to move into the corner too. But the pointer does detect it.